# How does 2a = 0 not imply a = 0 for a random field affect the fact that the set of n×n symmetric and skew matrices are a subspace and their dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

For a homework assignment I'm supposed to prove that the set of n×n symmetric matrices and the set of n×n skew matrices with the elements of the matrix being elements of a random field F are a subspace and find their respective dimensions. I feel pretty good about my solution, but we received the hint that 2a = 0 does not necessarily imply a = 0, and I'm a bit concerned that this never came up. I thought maybe in proving the closure of skew matrices with elements from a field with two elements under scalar multiplication might be a problem, but since $0×1 = 0×0 = 0 = - 0$ and $1×1 = 1$ and $1×0 = 0$ and 0 and 1 are additive inverses, it seems like it still works. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What's a "random field"?  Might $\mathbb F$ possibly be of characteristic $2$?

Comment: As to the direct relevance, consider a diagonal element, say $a_{1,1}$.  If the matrix is skew symmetric then we have $a_{1,1}=-a_{1,1}$ from which you would like to conclude that $a_{1,1}=0$, but you can't in general.

Comment: $1$ and $0$ are **not** additive inverses in the fields of two elements! To be additive inverses, I would expect $1 + 0 = 0 + 1 = 0$ (the right hand side is $0$, because that is the additive identity). However, this is not the case!

Comment: Oh of course, 1 and 0 are their own additive inverses, long day... Still I don't see that it affects the solution. In either case we still get the same matrix or the 0 matrix, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: The characteristic doesn't affect the fact that these are subspaces, but it affects the dimension of one of them.

Comment: Ah I think I got it now, the dimension of the vector space of nn skew matrixes is the same as the dimension of the nn symmetric matrixes for Z2. Thanks